# How are arguments passed into custom build tools for Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

When Visual Studio uses a custom build tool, how is the file being built and command line passed into the .exe file?

I'm assuming that the file and command line is passed into the files main function, but I do not have much else to go on. Any thoughts?

Edit: I want to create a build tool for processing custom files therefore I need to know how Visual Studio sends arguments and data to the executables.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What build tool are you using?

Comment: @MarkoPopovic Sorry about that. Im not using a build tool, I want to create one.

Comment: I would point you to the CMake tool, either for using it to create custom build targets or to have a look at the source code to see how it handles custom build tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio simply runs your executable with the arguments you provided just like any other application. If you create a build tool that will be called by Visual Studio like this

```
my_build_tool.exe /foobar C:\my\path\to\file.cpp
```

then you will access it in main function of your program in standard way:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // arg[1] points to "/foobar" and arg[2] points to "C:\my\path\to\file.cpp"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed.